# What does this GUI icon mean?

Tags: stardew-valley

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, there is a bunch of GUI stuff in the upper-righthand corner of the screen: time indicator, money counter, date, time and other.
There are also two small icons. Directly below the date, "Sun. 14", there is an icon defining current weather on the left. As you can see, it indicates that it is snowing. However, there is another icon to the right of it (directly below "14", red circle with green leaves), but I cannot figure out what it means.

What does it mean?

Comment: I like how it's snowing and she says "it's hot out here". Could be me as female.

Comment: That seems to be quite an [old bug](https://steamcommunity.com/app/413150/discussions/1/405693392924122433/)

Comment: @YUNOWORK or she is from Michigan and is experiencing her first light Philadelphia snow.

Comment: She's cute #sueme

Answer (score 45, accepted):

That icon indicates what season it is. The current icon is Winter, indicated by what appears to be a holly: [image]. Spring is a pink flower:
[image] Summer is a sailboat: [image] and Fall is a orange-yellow leaf: [image].

Comment: Ah Summer, when the sail-boat trees ripen.

Comment: Together with the number above, it makes up the date, since each season is 28 days long.